# ansible find first undefined value in list

Tags: ansible

I have a list in ansible and I want to find the first "unused" item in that list.

Example list:

```
item001
item002
item004
item005
item100
item101
```

The prefix numbers in the items could be up to 999

In the example above the result should be `item003`.

Here is an example playbook of what I want

```
---
- name: Test
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    my_list: []

    list1:
      - item107
      - item002
      - item004
      - item001
      - item007
      - item101
      - item604

  tasks:
    - name: Initialize a dummy list
      set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list|sort }} + [ '{{ item }}' ]"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=19 format=item%.3d

    - name: print first unused value in my_list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (my_list | difference(list1))[0] }}"
```

output:

```
PLAY [Test]     *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts]     ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Initialize a dummy list]     ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=item001)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item002)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item003)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item004)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item005)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item006)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item007)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item008)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item009)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item010)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item011)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item012)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item013)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item014)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item015)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item016)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item017)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item018)
ok: [localhost] => (item=item019)

TASK [print first unused value in my_list]     ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "item003"
}

PLAY RECAP     ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But if I change `with_sequence: start=1 end=19` to `with_sequence: start=1 end=999` the tasks takes very long time and also prints 999 lines in the output I really would love to not see.

Comment: what did you tried? post your work

Comment: Are you trying to use Ansible for programatic string processing? Maybe not ideal, though it can be done... [What have you tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Updated initial post with an example playbook to show what I want

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked better, didn't print any large output and was much quicker:

```
    - name: Initialize a dummy list
      set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ lookup('sequence', 'start=1 count=999 format=item%.3d', wantlist=True) }}"
```