# template error when using lookup in ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to generate some numbers using `lookup sequence` and along with `with_nested`. I followed this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/850620/565801) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099272/ansible-find-first-undefined-value-in-list) and it seems like its possible to do this. Unfortunately I'm getting the error `template error while templating string: unexpected char`. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char \"'\" at 22. String: {{ lookup('sequence', 'start"
}
```

Here is the task

```
  set_fact: "{{ lookup('sequence', 'start=1 end={{ count }} format=%02d', wantlist=True) }}"
```

Comment: Isn't `loookup` having 1 `o` too many? A typo.

Comment: Thats right. it was a typo in the playbook. But I'm getting a different error now. Any idea how to resolve this?

"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char \"'\" at 22. String: {{ lookup('sequence', 'start"

Comment: I would suggest not editing the same question each time you get a new error. Search and/or create a new question for that. Now no-one will be able to see the answer to the original question.

Comment: Agree with @JustLudo, you could have created a new question by setting proper context like -- "*I'm trying to generate some numbers*" -- to do what? What's your expected output? etc.

Answer (score 0):

set_fact wait a var :

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes 
  tasks: 
    - name: fact
      set_fact: 
        customvar: "{{ lookup('sequence', 'start=1 end={{ count }} format=%02d', wantlist=True) }}"
      vars:
        count: 5
    - name: Dump 
      debug: 
        var: customvar
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "customvar": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
    ]
}
```